# Read a select option on Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am attempting to get the value of the data from the select option which will actively decide what will be displayed on the same page. I need to get the child.id value and was wondering if there is a way to find this data without having to create a whole new page.

```
<select id="child">
        {% for cl in children %}
            {% if cl.parent == user %}
                <option value="{{child.id}}">{{ cl.first_name }}  {{ cl.last_name }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write simple JavaScript (use jQuery for convenience) here is the tutorial for the select value [link](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/)